# Socket Error 10053 (Too many packets being sent at once?) in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm creating a program in Delphi 7 which sends and receives packets from a server (which is not mine). It sends a packet, waits to receive the packet, and then reads it. All these procedures work properly, but when I loop the sendPacket procedure (which I need to do) it freezes and gives socket error 10053. I think this is because the server is refusing the request because of too many packets being sent in a short period of time. Are more than once packets being sent at the same time? I've tried putting a Sleep(1000) after the packet is sent.

Question: How do I limit the amount of packets that will be sent, or make it not send more than 1 packet at once?

```
begin
  if pack[1]='bf' 
  then
    if pack[3]='-1' 
    then 
      Label2.Caption:='Not Found'
    else
      begin
        found:=true;
        while found=true do 
          begin
            Pickle.sendPacket('%xt%s%u#bf%'+Pickle.intRoom+'%122868290%');
            room:= pack[3];
            Label2.Caption:='Found at the '+room;
            if room = '-1' 
            then 
              begin 
                Label2.Caption:='Left the server';  
                found:=false; 
              end;
          end;
      end;
end;
```

Comment: if you're sending UDP packets then Windows has some form of rate limiting built-in that may be the cause (I don't have a reference, this is just from memory)

Comment: Edited the question. I cleared up what I was actually asking.

Answer (score 3):

the following loop in your code won't be left until pack[3] will contain -1.

```
    while found=true do 
      begin
        Pickle.sendPacket('%xt%s%u#bf%'+Pickle.intRoom+'%122868290%');
        room:= pack[3];
        Label2.Caption:='Found at the '+room;
        if room = '-1' 
        then 
          begin 
            Label2.Caption:='Left the server';  
            found:=false; 
          end;
      end;
```

It's not shown where pack[3] is set. You should move your code into a receive event, without looping.

Comment: I need it to be looped until pack[3] contains -1. What's a receive event? (I'm new to Delphi)

Answer (score 0):

Figure out how often you need to update, and only send packets when needed.

For instance, only send packets when current room changes. If the room stays the same, why send it again and again?

If you want to send updates with a specified interval, use something like `Sleep(25);` every cycle.